# Why is [[maybe_unused]] in captured list not possible?

Tags: c++, c++17

I wonder why I can't use the [[maybe_unused]] attribute in the capture list of a lambda. Is there a reason that variables of a captured lists can't be marked as [[maybe_unused]]? This would avoid to capture all variables, means [&], in cases like this:

```
auto lambda = [&x, [[maybe_unused]] &y](){ 
    if constexpr( x >= 0) {
        return x;
    }
    else {
        return y;
    }
}
```

In each case where x >= 0 there is a compiler warning that y is not used. But if x < 0, there is no warning. My first try was to use [[maybe_unused]], but that is not possible.

My question: is there a reason, why I can't use the [[maybe_unused]] attribute in the capture list of lambda?

Comment: It wouldn't avoid capturing, the attribute is only there to supress compiler warnings about unused variables.

Comment: @super That's the point. In each case where x>=0 there is a compiler warning that y is not used. I like to supress the warning with maybe_unused.

Comment: You could use default capture. Just do `[&]() {...};` and it will only capture what you use.

Comment: If you want to be as explicit as possible, you can combine default capture with other explicit captures. `[&, &x]() {...};` for example.

Comment: Depending on the context of your actual code, you might want to turn this inside-out. Use a helper function or the conditional operator to do: if x >= 0 then return a lambda that captures and returns x, else return a lambda that captures and returns y.

Comment: I edit the question. I hope it is now more clear. What I am looking for is a reason why I cann't use [[maybe_unused]] in a lambda captured. I don't look for solutions, to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the same on the mailing list. The [answer from Arthur O'Dwyer](https://lists.isocpp.org/std-proposals/2019/12/0827.php) was:

> Ah, yes, that would be a place where [[maybe_unused]] might apply.
> However, for now, you can easily write
>
> ```
> (void)a;
> ```
>
> to suppress the warning: https://godbolt.org/z/7ZHSYz That's less
> cluttering to the code (thus easier to read and maintain), and also
> works in existing compilers (thus easier to deploy).
>
> "Yeah, but using this logic, isn't [[maybe_unused]] *completely*
> redundant and unnecessary and should never have been standardized?"
> AFAIK, yes.

Comment: Additionally the example in the question is a bug in clang warning -Wunused-lambda-capture. See https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35450

Comment: Correct. I ran into the same bug, which was discussed a few mails earlier. For the answer, I only cited the part that (too some degree) explains why there is no `maybe_unused` even outside of that bug.